# scenebuilder javafx cant find my controller class?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

This is my code for simple login username and password?:

```
package application;



import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Login1{
    @FXML
    private Label status;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtuser;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField txtpass;

    public void login(ActionEvent evnt) {
        if(txtuser.getText().equals("user")&&        txtpass.getText().equals("pass")){
            status.setText("login successfull");
        }else {
            status.setText("login failed");
        }

    }
}
```

what i dont understand is that im following a youtube video toturial step by step and it seemed that it didnt work for me i dont every step and repeated the video about 5 times doing the code again and again but the scene builder just cant find the controller class? :(

Comment: Take a look here : https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/connecting_scenebuilder_edited_fxml_to It explains a couple of things about the controller and the fxml file.

Comment: still doesnt work :(

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code ?

Comment: *SceneBuilder* can't find the controller? Or it can't be found at runtime? Please post the FXML

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like the if your FXML file is in your package where your controller class is.

Comment: Do it like what?